# How To Add % Based Image To CSS? (for fluid layout)

Tags: html, css

Okay so I want to have an image that I select through CSS to be fluid based, however, this is the problem that I run into.

This is what I think in my head I have to do, however, it doesn't work:

```
#image { background-image:pic.jpg; height:100%; width:100%; }
```

But, you can't have this tag use the "height:100%;", correct? You have to set it to a pixel width. But if I want it to be fluid.. then I can't set it to a pixel width, correct?

Is there another way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do note the value of background-image should be enclosed in the url function, like so: `url('pic.jpg')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it this way it will be fluid:

**HTML:**

`<img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/62777000/jpg/_62777247_62777242.jpg" alt="" />`

**CSS:**

​`img {
    width: 100%;
}​`

http://jsfiddle.net/7hMbQ/1/

Or if you want to stretch width and height to 100% try this (but the ratio will not be correct):

http://jsfiddle.net/7hMbQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "fluid" in the sense that I'm thinking of it (responsive design sort of 'fluid'), then setting the "max-width" to "100%" should make sure that the image never overflows past its container (or in other words, goes past 100% width).

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

EDIT: If your issue is making the height maintain the aspect ratio, just don't specify a height property, or if you need to override an attribute setting, set the height to auto (!important) too:

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto !important; }
```

Comment: well, no its not an issue of the image going over its container. its a problem where the image will not appear when it has two % based height & width together, i believe one of them has to be a pixel amt for it to appear. you know what i'm saying ?